# How can I generate JSON Schema in ZIO?

Tags: zio-json

I know there's a zio.schema library, so I can do this:

```scala
  val schema: Schema[Record] = DeriveSchema.gen
  println(schema)
```

And this does print a class having a complex-looking class structure, but what I need is JSON output conforming to the JSON schema standard (draft 4 or later).  Is this doable with this library?